# Foundation - Menu positioning without breaking sticky features

Tags: html, css, menu, sass, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation for the first time. I've found it's "Magellan" menu thingy, which makes the navigation sticky after scrolling down.

This feature works for me without problems, but i need to have the menu positioned on the bottom of the window right after header, which has 100% height. I managed to do that with margin-top and relative position, but both of them "broke" the sticky menu function.

When I used the margin-top method, the menu was sticky, but had the margin on itself, so it basically dissapeared on the top of the window.

I have a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9frYX.jpg) explaining what i need to make. The left side is what i have now and the right side is what I need to make.

So basically,i need to pull the menu up to appear on the bottom of the window, but work with the "Magellan sticky feature". Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Edit: I managed to fix it by setting margin-top: -45px; to body, but it feels kind of sloppy

Answer (score 0):

try to add this CSS code

```
.magellan-container{
    top:auto !important;
    bottom:0;
}
```